# Topological sort in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I read a few places which claim that its possible to do topological sort in linear time. 
One such claim is made here - They say - O(V+E)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

But the algo they have : has a for each inside a while loop. I think that makes it O(n^2) instead.

Then I found this solution - https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse326/03wi/lectures/RaoLect20.pdf - on slide 19 - apparantly they are looking for a faster way - but on second step of Step 3, they are looking for all adjacent nodes (inside a while loop), so that makes it O(n^2) too.

So is this case - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/

What am I missing here?

Comment: "has a for each inside a while loop. I think that makes it O(n^2) instead" - that doesn't mean it's O(n^2). You can't just look at the control flow structure of the program to determine its runtime, no matter what badly constructed big-O problem sets may have led you to believe.

Comment: The number of edges (E) is O(V^2), so O(V+E) is equal to O(V^2)

Comment: how is O(V+E) and O(V^2) same?

Comment: @aromero those are two different complexity classes, although one includes the other

Answer (score 8):

> has a for each inside a while loop. I think that makes it O(n^2) instead.

If you use an adjacency list representation of your graph, you look at every edge exactly once in the inner loop, so it's O(max {n, m}) = O(n + m).

Of course it is also O(n^2), but that is not a tight upper bound.

> they are looking for all adjacent nodes (inside a while loop), so that makes it O(n^2) too.

Again, it's also O(n + m) if you use adjacency lists to represent your graph.

Comment: Even with adjacency list - you look at n edges ( even though exactly once ) for every m nodes. So that makes it O(mn) not O(m+n). Is that not correct?

Comment: @ND27 you seem to confuse something here. m is the number of edges, not nodes. And for every node x you look at outdegree(x) edges. The sum of all outdegrees is m, which is the total runtime (unless there are nodes than edges). Try to compute for evey line of code how often it is  executed. Then add all those up. The result is the runtime complexity of the algorithm, which you can then normalize to a big-O bound